# How to process data stream with Tensorflow and FIFOQueue

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue

I am trying to process data that arrives continuously in a neural network. To optimize the entire process, I have:

- A thread that is responsible for filling the FIFOQueue.
- Another thread that should extract as many elements as possible from the queue up to a threshold. That is: min(queue.size(), MAX_BATCH_SIZE). MAX_BATCH_SIZE is the maximum that I am capable of processing at the same time.

I have managed to make it work, but it is something rudimentary and I wonder if there is a better implementation of this method. I focus on the consumer thread of the queue.

**Definition of operations:**

```
self.queue = tf.FIFOQueue ...
self.input_dequeue_op = self.queue.dequeue_many(
                                tf.maximum(
                                    tf.constant(1), 
                                    tf.minimum(
                                        tf.constant(MAX_BATCH_SIZE), 
                                        self.queue.size()
                                    )
                                )
                            )
```

**Consumer Thread:**

```
with network.sess.as_default():
    while True:

            results = network.sess.run(self.input_dequeue_op)
```

Basically what I intend is to send to a neural network the maximum number of elements that are currently in the queue up to MAX_BATCH_SIZE (which is the maximum that can be processed at the same time).

The operation obtains the maximum real batch that I can load.
It seems to me a very rudimentary form, I have also tried to use it directly:

```
self.input_dequeue_op = self.queue.dequeue_up_to(tf.constant(MAX_BATCH_SIZE))
```

But the queue is blocked indefinitely even if elements are added.

Is there another better way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the nature of your application? For example, are you running inference or are you looking to train a model?

Comment: Inference, the model is already trained. The system acts as a daemon continually waiting for images to be processed, but since it runs on the GPU to optimize the process, it takes the largest batch that the network can process at the same time: max (1, min (q.size (), MAX_BATCH_SIZE)).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Somehow missed the notification. Have you thought about using QueueRunners and Coordinators? They do a much better job of managing different threads so that blocking or queues running dry never happens.

Comment: It's not a problem, I appreciate your help. On the one hand, the system uses a daemon that consumes the FIFOQueue (a single thread) and on the other hand multiple threads are used to fill the queue (one per request). These threads also perform other operations and for this reason the python standards are used.
Is it possible to do this with the new api tf.data?

Comment: there is a [parallel_interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave) method that can possibly construct a tf.data dataset by pulling data from various files, which seems to be something similar to what youre trying to achieve here. But I am not sure about how optimized such a solution would be for inference. For training, you would have larger disparate data sources and you need to load all of them repeatedly.